# Upper bound for smallest eigenvalue of matrix $A = \mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mu}[\phi(x)\phi(x)^\top]$ where $\|\phi(x)\|_2 \leq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, expected-value

I am reading a paper which claims the following. But I am not sure how to show it rigorously. Any help is appreciated.

For all $x\in \mathcal{X}$, assume the $d$-dimensional feature map is bounded such that $\|\phi(x)\|_2 \leq 1$. For any data distribution $\mu$ consider the matrix $$A = \mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mu}[\phi(x)\phi(x)^\top]$$

Prove that the largest possible minimum eigenvalue $\sigma_{\text{min}}$ of matrix $A$ satisfies
$$\sigma_{\text{min}}(A) \leq \frac{1}{d}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is a $d\times d$ positive semidefinite matrix, its eigenvalues are nonnegative and they coincide with the singular values of $A$. Therefore
\begin{align}
\sigma_\min(A)
=\lambda_\min(A)
&\le\frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i(A)
=\frac{1}{d}\operatorname{tr}(A)\\
&=\frac{1}{d}\operatorname{tr}\left(\mathbb E\left(\phi\phi^\top\right)\right)
=\frac{1}{d}\mathbb E\left(\operatorname{tr}(\phi\phi^\top)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{d}\mathbb E\left(\|\phi\|_2^2\right)
\le\frac{1}{d}\mathbb E(1)
=\frac{1}{d}.
\end{align}